# xpath matches function expression for same name node content

Tags: java, regex, xpath, nodes

With the example below, I can not run following XPath expression: `//Test[matches(Name1/text(),".*text.*")]` and ExpressionExpection be triggers. As against the expression `//Test[matches(Name/text(),".*text.*")]` work normally!
Please explain why and how this problem be paid? because I spent a lot of time on it without result.
Thank you in advance.
My exemple:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
  <Test txt="0001" >
    <Name1>text1</Name1>
    <Name2>text2</Name2>
    <Name3>text3</Name3>
  </Test>
  <Test txt="0002" >
    <Name>text4</Name>
    <Name>text5</Name>
    <Name>text6</Name>
  </Test>
 </Root>
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you please provide your complete code.

Comment: Are you sure it is not the other way round? I would `//Test[matches(Name/text(),".*text.*")]` expect to tell you that the first argument to `matches` can't be a sequence of more than one item. To correct that problem you can use `//Test[Name[matches(., '.*text.*')]]`.

Comment: thanks Lingamurthy CS for you interest, this also worked for me but in a online  xPath tester, I think the problem depends on the used package java xpath  in my program!

Comment: thank you very much @MartinHonnen, the problem was really for this. The first argument of matches() gives more nodes in my second expression. I tried your suggestion and it worked well. thank you very much

Comment: @abaraa23000, I have put my comment into an answer you should be able to accept to have this question properly resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell the expression `//Test[matches(Name/text(),".*text.*")]` can give you an error with your input sample that a sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of `matches`.

To avoid that problem, simply use `//Test[Name[matches(., '.*text.*')]]`.

The expression `//Test[matches(Name1/text(),".*text.*")]` should work for your sample as there is only a single `Name1` child.